# Boost does not apply on elasticsearch function_score

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-6.3.1. The following query works as expected:

```
"query": {
    "function_score" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
      },
      "functions" : [
        {
          "filter" : {
            "match_all" : {}
          },
          "script_score" : {
            "script" : { "source" : "8" }
          }
        },
        {
          "filter" : {
            "match_all" : {}
          },
          "script_score" : {
            "script" : { "source" : "4" }
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode" : "avg",
      "boost" : 0.5
    }
  }
```

returning a score of 3 (the average(6) times the boost(0.5)).

If I remove one of the functions, though

```
"query": {
  "function_score" : {
    "query" : {
      "match_all" : {}
    },
    "functions" : [
      {
        "filter" : {
          "match_all" : {}
        },
        "script_score" : {
          "script" : { "source" : "8" }
        }
      }
    ],
    "score_mode" : "avg",
    "boost" : 0.5
  }
}
```

I get a score of 8, not applying the boost. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an elasticsearch bug, but I don't see any ticket in the GitHub issue tracker.

Weirder: this query works fine (just replacing the script_score with a plain weight )

```
 {
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "weight": 8
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "avg",
      "boost": 0.5
    }
  }
}
```

=> give a `_score` of 4

So it seems ES doesn't apply boost when the only function is a script_score -_-!

Comment: Thanks. I have opened a ticket [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/35123)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding a "weight" of 1 to the function(s) fixes the issue.